# Why is my site's flaoted sidebar collapsing?

Tags: html, css

I floated the sidebar on my site and it seems to collapse down from the main content section? How do I go about keep it at the same level?

My site: bryanseacrest.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sidebar is a little bit large in width.

You can decrease either the width of your sidebar or the width of your content.

**BUT** I think the best way to fix it is to increase the width of your wrapper.